# XML Name space issue revisited

Tags: regex, perl, libxml2

**XML Name space issue revisited:**

I am still not able to find a good solution to the problem that the findnode or findvalue does not work when we have xmlns has some value.

The moment I set manually `xmlns=""`, it starts working. At least in my case. Now I need to automate this.

consider this

```
< root xmlns="something" >
--
---
< /root>
```

My recommended solution :

1. dynamically set the value to `xmlns=""`
2. and when the work is done automatically we can reset to the original value `xmlns="something"`

And this seems to be a working solution for my XMLs only but its stll manual.

I need to automate this:

How to do it 2 options:

1. using Perl regex, or
2. using proper LibXML setNamespace etc.

Please put your thought in this context.

Comment: What if there are several namespaces in the document? Definitely use the proper way, i.e. register the namespace.

Comment: As I mentioned I have just one.

Answer (score 1):

You register the namespace.  The point of XML is not having to kludge around with regexes!

Besides, it's *easier*: you create an `XML::LibXML::XPathContext`, register your namespaces, and use its find* calls with your chosen prefixes.

The following example is verbatim from a script of mine to list references in Visual Studio projects:

```
(...)
# namespace handling, see the XML::LibXML::Node documentation
my $xpc = new XML::LibXML::XPathContext;
$xpc->registerNs( 'msb',
   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003' );
(...)
my $tree; eval { $tree = $parser->parse_file($projfile) };
(...)
my $root = $tree->getDocumentElement;
(...)
foreach my $attr ( find( '//msb:*/@Include', $root ) )
{
   (...)
}
(...)
sub find { $xpc->find(@_)->get_nodelist; }
(...)
```

That's all it takes!

Comment: thanks friend. But I have too many XMLs coming in to process. And my request is to automate the xmlns part. If I have to get the xmlns from XML and put it in the script manually, then I would rather remove it it from XML itself in lesser time. Which means no automation needed!!

Comment: Good point ... but can't you predict the xmlns values in those documents?

Answer (score 1):

I only have one xmlns attribuite at the top of the XML once only so this works for me.

All I did was first to remove the namespace part i.e. remove the xmlns from my XML file.

```
NODE : for my $node ($conn->findnodes("//*[name()='root']")) {

   my $att = $node->getAttribute('xmlns'); 

    $node->setAttribute('xmlns', ""); 

        last NODE;

}
```

using **last** just to make sure i come of the for loop in time.

And then once I am done with the XML parsing I will replace the

```
<root>
```

with

```
<root xmlns="something">
```

using simple Perl file operation or **sed** editor.